# Javascript: How to randomize images on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a one page website right now and I want to add an randomize image every time that the page was load. Before I'm using PHP to randomized my carousel by using  **`ORDER BY rand()`** while **selecting** data. Right now I am looking for a javascript code to randomized images **NOT USING ANY DATABASE**. I accept any suggestion, my code are the following below:

```
<!-- start home -->
<section id="home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                <h1 class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="50" data-wow-delay="0.9s">We make paper products that are <span>awesome</span></h1>
                <div class="element">
                    <div class="sub-element">Hello, this is WhatWeAre</div>
                    <div class="sub-element">Paper for everyone</div>
                    <div class="sub-element">Contact us and we make your products while conserving environment </div>
                </div>
                <a data-scroll href="#about" class="btn btn-default wow fadeInUp" data-wow-offset="50" data-wow-delay="0.6s">GET STARTED</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end home -->

<style type="text/css">
 #home{
    background: url('../images/home_1.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 160px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    min-height: 650px;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Okay we've have he same problem sir. This question is very useful not only for me but for everybody. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got an answer with some sites. Not making any changes with my CSS stylesheet and NOT even using database. Here the following codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if (document.getElementById) { 
    window.onload = swap 
};
function swap() {
    var numimages=7;

    rndimg = new Array("images/home.jpeg","images/home-bg.jpg","images/home_1.jpg");
    x=(Math.floor(Math.random()*numimages));
    randomimage=(rndimg[x]);
    document.getElementById("home").style.backgroundImage = "url("+ randomimage +")"; 
}   
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need the `if (document.getElementById)` test, unless you're trying to support IE4. And you should declare all variables with `var`. Also, use `rndimg.length` rather than `numimages`, to automatically adjust to whatever size the array is...

Comment: So you didn't wanted to **generate** these images... And you've go a *database* : `Array("images/home.jpeg","images/home-bg.jpg","images/home_1.jpg")` Even if it is hard-coded in your html file.

Comment: Yes, I just have a predefined images and get it using array. I put it on my custom script.

Comment: Nice shot, you've got you're answer with your complicated question. Thank for this it help me a lot.